# What is the meaning of the sentence- [ a ConcurrentHashMap cannot be locked for exclusive access]?

Tags: java

**Joshua Block & co-authors** of the famous **Java Concurrentcy In Practice** put forwards-

This is from *Chapter 5 Building Blocks*-

> ...Since a ConcurrentHashMap cannot be locked for exclusive
>   access.....

What I understand is exclusive access refers to the locking the whole collection with each thread holding a lock for the duration of the operations to make them atomic.

```
    ConcurrentHashMap< String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap< String, String>();

    public void getExclusiveAccess(){
        synchronized (map) {
            //....
        }
    }
```

Even though this would be stupidity to do something like above, but clearly exclusive access is achievable through the same.
Please suggest.
Why does the author says that **a ConcurrentHashMap cannot be locked for exclusive access** ?

Answer (score 2):

I have done this and it's achievable however, it only works with this external locking and is not supported by `ConcurrentMap`.  If you access the map anywhere without using this synchronization, it won't be exclusive. If you use synchronized everywhere it's not concurrent any more.

The only time this might make sense is if you need exclusive write but not exclusive read.

Comment: And this is clearly client side locking. So why do the authors mentioned - **Since a ConcurrentHashMap cannot be locked for exclusive access, we cannot use client-side locking to create new atomic operations such as put-if-absent,** I know that there are already atomic operations inside a concurrent map to do the same.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari ConcurrentMap doesn't support this, this doesn't prevent you implementing your own solution, but you won't get any support from the implementation in doing this.

Comment: I think this example code would help: https://ideone.com/N6tIRI, in understanding what Peter/author of the book wants to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

> clearly exclusive access is achievable through the same

not if some other code uses the map outside a synchronized block (which is perfectly acceptable).

This is different from, say, a `synchronizedMap` where all the methods are synchronized on the map itself - so if you `synchronized(map) {... }` on such a map, you effectively have exclusive access.

Comment: But I am only taking about the case in which I am clearly having a exclusive access. Does `synchronized (map) {
            //....
        }` even guarantees exclusive access for this case.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari CHM implementation itself does not support exclusive access. Now you can always enforce exclusive access by using client side locking, of course... But that's very different from a `Collections.synchronizedMap()` which does provide exclusive access at the implementation level.